# N2 CMS custom theme/skin development

Tags: layout, themes, n2cms

I m new to N2CMS and working on Form Template to design a website.
I have a theme & layout from customer.But i m unable to integrate it with N2.
I want to make custom modifications like Layout modifications.
Where should i put Assets Like CSS,Images and where should i insert Masterpage or a Layout which will be followed by whole site?
I m not able to find specific links on web even N2CMS documentation is able to define this.
I have Artisteer template which i wnt to integrate.

Please help 
Thnx in Advance

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your first reference to develop N2 web site should be the [Templates pack](http://n2cms.codeplex.com/downloads/get/264787).

*Where should i put Assets Like CSS,Images*

In the Templates pack, go to App_Themes folder where you can see many skin folders listed where CSS and images are putted.

*where should i insert Masterpage or a Layout which will be followed by whole site?*

Here is the path of the master page :Templates / UI / Layouts / Top+SubMenu.